# How to create own javascript api similar to google analytics

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics-api

I just want to know how google analytics works and what this code means?

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'some value']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: should have checked https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview

Comment: First of, Welcome to StackOverflow! As you this is not a place where someone else will do your job for free. Try to do some research on the topic first, ask specific questions, and what Problems are you experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a broad question but you may find some useful information here https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview

It shows you [what the code actually does](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#gifParameters) as well as [describing all of the parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#gifParameters).

Comment: Thank u for giving me link. Do know any article or website which can help me to write own api like google analytics and zopim doing.

Comment: That seems like quite a large undertaking (If you want the same functionality), if possible I would suggest you use Google Analytics rather than building your own solution. Is there any reason why this wouldn't be possible?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to read up on Google analytic's, but in terms of that code:

```
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Is injecting a external javascript resource into your page

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'some value']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

is creating (if doesnt exist) and adding values to a javascript array

To learn how it works you'll need to seek out the documentation or go on a course (of which I believe there are millions)

Answer (score 0):

what this does is it creates an object with some properties (first 3 lines) then it injects a script tag into the document, once the script loads it will take that js object and utilize it for the tracking.

Answer (score 0):

This code insert a external scrypt in your page.
By `_gaq` holds your specific settings, and the function below adds a `<script>` above the first script tag in your page